# Why I am getting global name 'http' is not defined error?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using tastypie. When I want to post data to my server I am getting:

"global name 'http' is not defined"

Error message.

My curl command is

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{{"shop" : "/api/shop/1/","transactions" : [{"item" : "/api/item/53/","note" : "Normal"}]}' http://localhost:5000/api/order/
```

Traceback:

```
{"error_message": "global name 'http' is not defined", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/Users/burakkilic/Documents/Projects/FineDine/Server/Django/finedine/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/burakkilic/Documents/Projects/FineDine/Server/Django/finedine/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/burakkilic/Documents/Projects/FineDine/Server/Django/finedine/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/burakkilic/Documents/Projects/FineDine/Server/Django/finedine/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1317, in post_list\n    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  File \"/Users/burakkilic/Documents/Projects/FineDine/Server/Django/finedine/finedine/api.py\", line 203, in deserialize\n    raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=http.HttpBadRequest(e.message))\n\nNameError: global name 'http' is not defined\n"}
```

I put the address in quotes, but nothing has changed.

Also I wrote this to my resource:

```
def deserialize(self, request, data, format='application/json'):
    try:
        return super(OrderResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format=format)
    except Exception as e:
        # if an exception occurred here it must be due to deserialization
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=http.HttpBadRequest(e.message))
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Put the address in quotes.

Comment: Please check my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception handler in that resource expects `http` to be in the local namespace:

```
raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=http.HttpBadRequest(e.message))
```

If you don't have something like `from tastypie import http` earlier in your code, this will fail.

As an aside, for small things like this I generally prefer to use something like `from tastypie.http import HttpBadRequest` to catch incorrect names immediately using a tool like [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) or [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8). If the only reference to `HttpBadRequest` was in infrequently-executed code like that `except` block it can take awhile before you notice a problem like this.